# How can I send a request to HTTP://localhost/somephp.php from HTTPS://some.where/?

Tags: http, https, xmlhttprequest, localhost

#### Background

I was making a browser extension that sends a POST request to `http://ip.v4.ad.dr/somephp.php` which does some data handling based on the POSTed data.  This extension is supposed to function on the site `https://meet.google.com/`.

#### Problem

My problem arises because I am sending from `https` to `http`, so my request is blocked and this error appears:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://meet.google.com/mym-eets-url?authuser=x' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ip.v4.ad.dr/somephp.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

<sup>Please note that those are fake URLs.  They are just there to signify that this is what the URL looks like, not what it is.  mym-eets-url is My Meet's URL, and ip.v4.ad.dr is IPv4 Address</sup>

#### Attempts to solve

I have thought of:

1. Making/using some site that reflects the request to the target URL.  I do not think this works since that mirror site may block the request, since it is `https`.
2. Making my `localhost` use `https`.  I am pretty sure this will work, but I don't want to use `https` simply because the request won't send otherwise.  I can try doing this if there isn't any other option.

#### Question

What is the best way to send a request from a `https` site to my own `http://ip.v4.ad.dr/` server?